# JavaFX 3D Rotate camera Y around latitude

Tags: java, javafx, 3d

I have defined a camera that rotates around the scene's origin, with a Rotate X axis, and a Rotate Y axis.

I would like that the X axis defines the "height" of my Y axis camera so that it revolves around the given latitude on the sphere.

[image: sphere]

I have defined the rotates as such:

```
    _cameraTranslate = new Translate(0, 0, -10);
    _cameraRotateX = new MyRotate(0, 0, 0, 10, Rotate.X_AXIS);
    _cameraRotateY = new MyRotate(0, 0, 0, 10, Rotate.Y_AXIS);
    _camera.getTransforms().addAll(_cameraTranslate, _cameraRotateX, _cameraRotateY);
```

And rotate them as such:

```
private void onMouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    _cameraRotateX.setAngle360(_cameraRotateX.getAngle() - (-e.getSceneY() + _mouseOldY));
    _cameraRotateY.setAngle360(_cameraRotateY.getAngle() - (e.getSceneX() - _mouseOldX));

    _mouseOldX = e.getSceneX();
    _mouseOldY = e.getSceneY();
}
```

This is what it does when I rotate around, shifting the world instead of keeping the X axis lines parallel to the frame if it makes sense.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I realized I have to modify the axis of the X camera (the one going up and down). As the camera rotates around the Y axis, the X and Z axes move so the rotation needs to be adapted accordingly.

Instead, I added a Point3D that I modify every time the Y camera is moved:

```
_cameraRotateXAxis = new Point3D(1, 0, 0);
_cameraRotateX = new MyRotate(0, 0, 0, 10, _cameraRotateXAxis);
```

And in the mouseDragged method:

```
private void onMouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    _cameraRotateX.setAngle360(_cameraRotateX.getAngle() - (-e.getSceneY() + _mouseOldY));
    _cameraRotateY.setAngle360(_cameraRotateY.getAngle() - (e.getSceneX() - _mouseOldX));

    _cameraRotateXAxis = _cameraRotateXAxis.add(-_cameraRotateXAxis.getX(), -_cameraRotateXAxis.getY(), -_cameraRotateXAxis.getZ());

    double angle = _cameraRotateY.getAngle();
    double newDelta = _cameraRotateY.getAngle()%90 / 90d;
    if (angle >= 0 && angle < 90) {
        _cameraRotateXAxis = _cameraRotateXAxis.add(-(1 - newDelta), 0, newDelta);
    }
    else if (angle >= 90 && angle < 180) {
        _cameraRotateXAxis = _cameraRotateXAxis.add(newDelta, 0, 1 -newDelta);
    }
    else if (angle >= 180 && angle < 270) {
        _cameraRotateXAxis = _cameraRotateXAxis.add(1 - newDelta, 0, -newDelta);
    }
    else {
        _cameraRotateXAxis = _cameraRotateXAxis.add(-newDelta, 0, -(1 - newDelta));
    }

    _mouseOldX = e.getSceneX();
    _mouseOldY = e.getSceneY();
}
```